# How to install Griffon plugin behind proxy

Tags: griffon

I am trying to install some plugin into Griffon by issuing this command

```
griffon install-plugin miglayout
```

But I get error:

> Welcome to Griffon 1.0.0 - http://griffon-framework.org/ Licensed
>   under Apache Standard License 2.0 Griffon home is set to:
>   /usr/local/share/Griffon-1.0.0
>
> Base Directory: /home/biske/Griffon examples/form Running script
>   /usr/local/share/Griffon-1.0.0/scripts/InstallPlugin_.groovy Resolving
>   dependencies... Dependencies resolved in 304ms. Environment set to
>   development Failed to install plugin miglayout [offline: false]

I am using Griffon Griffon 1.0.0.
It fails because network has proxy. Is there a way to install plugin if there is proxy enabled in network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the add-proxy / set-proxy commands?

http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html

http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html

http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/ref/Command%20Line/clear-proxy.html

http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/ref/Command%20Line/remove-proxy.html

Comment: Now I am getting following error: `Some dependencies could not be resolved.
-= INSTALLED =-
. swing-1.0.0
-= MISSING =-
? swing-0.9.5 from griffon-local
Could not resolve plugin dependencies.
`

Comment: The answer is found here http://www.jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/the_griffon_trove_troubleshooting_plugin